# SQL Character extraction

Tags: sql

I would like to extract everything on the right side of the "underscore". I want to get 0000. I tried

```
select right('M_0000',charindex('_','M_0000')-1)
```

but end up with just 0. Why?

Comment: which RDBMS are we talking about?

Comment: why cant you do this: `SELECT right('M_0000',4)`

Comment: The number of characters after the underscore changes. It is not always just 4. I am using "m_0000" as an example. I am using SQL Server.

Comment: It should return the right most character, which happens to be 0 and so the result is correct, change the parameter of `right` to M_0001 and you will see the difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using CHARINDEX, i assume you are using SQL-SERVER.

So in your second field you should say how many characters you want. You can achieve that by doing `LEN('M_0000') - charindex('_')` :

```
select right('M_0000',len('M_0000') - charindex('_','M_0000'))
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/26158)</kbd>

You were ending up with just one 0 because charindex('_') is 1, and you are telling the RIGHT function that you want 1 char from the right.

From the [docs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx):

> **RIGHT** ( character_expression , integer_expression )
>
> **character_expression** Is an expression of character or binary data.
> character_expression can be a constant, variable, or column.
> character_expression can be of any data type, except text or ntext,
> that can be implicitly converted to varchar or nvarchar. Otherwise,
> use the CAST function to explicitly convert character_expression.
>
> **integer_expression** Is a positive integer that specifies how many
> characters of character_expression will be returned. If
> integer_expression is negative, an error is returned. If
> integer_expression is type bigint and contains a large value,
> character_expression must be of a large data type such as
> varchar(max).

Comment: This worked. Alittle confused because I can do: select left('lm_0000',charindex('_','lm_0000')-1) and get all the values to the left of the underscore without specifying a "length".

Comment: That's because when you do left, you can use charindex, because the index of _ is where you want to stop. It's the difference between counting from the left and from the right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUBSTRING` instead of `RIGHT`:

```
select SUBSTRING('M_0000',charindex('_','M_0000')+1, LEN('M_0000'))   // start at character n + 1
```